XeLaTeX: fallback specifically for monospace
I'm using a package that ends up delegating to pygments for some code rendering. I use ≡ and ∈ as symbols within the code, which lmmono10-regular complains about not having.
What can I add to the prelude s.t. ∈ and ≡ characters delegate to a font that supports them, without changing the existing look of the document?
I've tried
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{∈}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\in$}}
\newunicodechar{≡}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\equiv$}}

but this leads to the characters not being the same proportion as the rest of the monospace.
I'm worried about ucharclasses, as I don't want to change to a monospace font when ∈ or ≡ get used in normal text.

Can you turn your snippet into something people can compile to test? Does New CM provide anything more useful in mono?

I'm not sure if I can. The code that's fed into pygments in generated by alectryon; various attempts I've made to use something other than \makebox, or use a custom font in \makebox, have all broken in some way...

For the record, I think \texttt{∈≡} would do it. I would be shocked if code snippets use a different font than \texttt.

Not sure if you're talking to me but, for what it's worth, you've lost me. Sorry.

I don't know what you mean by New CM, I was responding to the first part of your question.
